# Number of events in Solidity code vs on Etherscan

Tags: solidity, blockchain, etherscan, events, hex

Hey guys I have a simple Solidity code, which emits events shown in the code bellow.
What I don't understand however is that on Etherscan I get many sections with events that I have never coded. Why is that happening?

Contract address: 0x5b6c5f2032C2483251C36DA4EAd2EEe9504694dd

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract CallTestContract {

event NewTrade(
    string message,
    uint indexed date,
    address indexed from,
    address indexed to, // Only three indexed variables are allowed in an event
    uint amount,
    uint transaction
);
function Trade(string calldata _message, address to, uint amount) external payable{
    emit NewTrade(_message, block.timestamp, msg.sender, to, amount, msg.value);
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output your seeing corresponds to how solidity turns emitted events into logs.

First of all - you can have up to three indexed parameters in your event. These indexed parameters appear as topic1 - topic3. Topic0 is the hash of the event signature.

```
topic0 = keccack256("NewTrade(string,uint256,address,address,uint256,uint256)")
topic1 = date
topic2 = from
topic3 = to
```

Now for the un-indexed parameters. You may be expecting to find the un-indexed parameters packed together in order with the remaining log data. But what really happens is the rest of the parameters are encoded using `abi.encode`. This specification with similar examples to what you are dealing with can be found [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html#formal-specification-of-the-encoding).

In this case, since you are using a dynamic type, a string, the hex represents the following:

```
[line 1] = since the first non-indexed param is a string which is a dynamic type, this is an offset to the start of where the `message` parameter begins = 32*3 bytes = 96 = 0x60
[line 2] = amount 
[line 3] = transaction 
[line 4] = length of string (in hex)
[line 5 & 6] = your string in hex padded to 32 bytes on the right
```